# Adding checkbox array into one row of sql database

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

I have a checkbox array called `extras[]`. It is in a submisson form and along with a whole bunch of other values i.e name etc.

My problem is i cannot get the checkbox values to add to the database. *Note 6 check boxes of which all, none or some may be checked.

this is my code

```
 $q="INSERT INTO bs_reservations (dateCreated, name, email, phone, comments,status,eventID, qty,dropoff,deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine,price,duration,suburb,postcode,pickup) 
VALUES (NOW(),'".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$comments."','1','".$eventID."','".$qty."','".$dropoff."','{$extras[0]}','{$extras[1]}','{$extras[2]}','{$extras[3]}','{$extras[4]}','{$extras[5]}','".$price."','".$duration."','".$suburb."','".$postcode."','".$pickup."')";
    $res=mysql_query($q) or die("error!");
    $orderID=mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: No idear how you are getting values into those variables or if there is anything in there at all from the submit.

Comment: I have a separate form. All the values insert fine at the moment EXCEPT for the extra array.

Comment: oh try doing concatenation rather than single quoting them. Assuming that $extras[0] has a value and is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a default-value(0 or similar, I don't know which values you use there) for every checkbox, because if they are not checked, they will not be submitted:

```
$extra0=(isset($_POST['extras'][0]))?$_POST['extras'][0]:0;
$extra1=(isset($_POST['extras'][1]))?$_POST['extras'][1]:0;
//and so on
```

Comment: I think they could be submitted as NULL if the column allows and nothing is there to be submitted?